# A family of polynomials whose zeros all lie on the unit circle

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, polynomials, mp.mathematical-physics, zeroes

I had posted the following problem on [stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2722893/the-modulus-of-a-polynomial-are-the-same-is-1)  before.

> Suppose $\lambda$ is a real number in $\left( 0,1\right)$, and let $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that all the roots of the polynomial $$
> f\left ( x \right )=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\lambda^{k\left ( n-k \right )}x^{k}
> $$ have modulus $1$.

I do not seem to know how to do it, to show if the roots of the polynomial have modulus one.  [Putnam 2014 B4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054826/show-all-roots-of-sum-k-0n-2kn-k-xk-are-real-december-6-2014-putna?rq=1) Show that for each positive integer $n,$ all the roots of the polynomial $\sum_{k=0}^n 2^{k(n-k)}x^k$ are real numbers.
This problem  is very similar to the Putnam problem.

Comment: One key observation is that the polynomial is palindromic, and with real coefficients, that is, $x^nf(1/x) = f(x)$. Thus, apriori, roots come in quadruplets, $z$, $1/z$ and their conjugates. Somehow, the binomial coefficients forces all such quadruplets to "degenerate" and essentially be roots paired with their inverse-conjugate.

Comment: Possibly related to the following MO problem: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296465 In any case, the $k(n-k)$ exponent appears there, too.

Comment: Putting $y:=\lambda^nx$, we have $$f(x)=g(y):=  
 \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\lambda^{-k^2}y^{k}= \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(\lambda^{-k}y)^{k},$$ so equivalently $g$ should have all zeros  of modulus $\lambda^n$. Not sure if that helps, it rather looks more weird.

Comment: Where does the question come from? Why do you believe this to be true?

Comment: I am not sure what the intended solution of the Putnam problem is, but I assume that this follows from the fact that the coefficient sequence of your second polynomial is log concave. This, of course, is false of the first polynomial, however, I believe the argument should go as follows: 1. Your polynomial is palindromic, so $f(x) = g(x+1/x)$ for some polynomial $g$ (with real coefficients. Such a polynomial can be obtained by simple linear algebra, or by using a basis of Chebyshev polynomials. 2. The coefficient sequence of $g$ should be log concave, so all of its roots should be real, so all

Comment: I don't think it suffices that the roots of $g$ are real: they have to lie in $[-2,2]$ as well. Otherwise, $f$ could have a root at, say, $10$ and $1/10$, in which case $g$ would have a root at $10+1/10$.

Comment: @Wouter Yes, you are right - typing in a hurry...

Comment: The "degeneracy" of the root quadruplets would be explained if $f(x)$ could be factored into second-degree palindromic polynomials: $f(x)=\prod_i (a_i+b_i x+a_i x^2)$, with real $a_i,b_i$. This is possible at least for $n=2,n=4$, but showing it in general does not appear easy.

Comment: In fact, $f(x)=\prod_i (1+b_i x+x^2)$. The relation between $\lambda$ and the $b_i$ is complicated, but if it could be established that $\lambda\in [0,1]\implies b_i\in[-2,2]$, that would prove it.

Comment: This is equivalent to the real polynomial  $g(x)=(x+i)^nf(\frac{x-i}{x+i})=\sum_{n=0}^k {n \choose k} \lambda^{k(n-k)}(x-i)^k(x+i)^{n-k}$ having all roots real and the roots interlace and for every fixed integer $k$ the, kth largest root goes to $\infty$. So on the circle, the $k$ nearest root to $1$ moves towards $1$ and converge to $1$ along the arc. For $\lambda>1$ the roots of $g(x)$ are pure imaginary and interlace as well.

Comment: The result follows immediately from the Lee-Yang Circle Theorem. See for instance Theorem 17.5 of https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~shayan/courses/cse599-s/counting-17.pdf.

Comment: See Appendix B here for a generalization: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2211.03678.pdf

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is a special case of the Lee-Yang theorem.  Let $G$ be a finite graph with vertex set $V$ and edge set $E$.  Let $\beta \in (0,1)$ be a real number.  Let $\sigma$ denote a ``spin function" $\sigma: V \to \{ -1, 1\}$.  Put $m(\sigma)$ to be the number of vertices with positive spin, and $d(\sigma)$ to be the number of edges with vertices of opposite spin.  Form the polynomial 
$$ 
Z_\beta(x) = \sum_{\sigma} \beta^{d(\sigma)} x^{m(\sigma)}, 
$$ 
where the sum is over all possible choices of the spins $\sigma$.  The Lee-Yang theorem then states that all the zeros of $Z_{\beta}(x)$ lie on the unit circle.  Amazing!

Apply the Lee-Yang theorem to the complete graph on $n$ vertices.  The polynomial $Z_{\beta}(x)$ in this case is exactly $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \beta^{k(n-k)} x^k$, and so this polynomial has all its roots on the unit circle.

For a discussion of the Lee-Yang theorem see these [notes](https://math.berkeley.edu/~nikhil/courses/270/lec15.pdf) from a course by Nikhil Srivastava.  The original Lee-Yang paper can be found [here](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.87.410) (behind a paywall).  For more work on the Lee-Yang theorem (among other things), see [Borcea and Branden](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.3087.pdf).  In particular, Theorem 8.4 there states the following more general form of the Lee-Yang theorem:  Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be a Hermitian $n\times n$ matrix with all entries inside the closed unit disc.  Then the polynomial 
$$ 
f(z) = \sum_{S\subset [n]} z^{|S|} \prod_{\substack{i\in S \\ j\not\in S}} a_{ij} 
$$ 
has all its zeros on the unit circle.  (Here $S$ runs over all subsets of $[n]=\{1, \ldots, n\}$.)

Comment: Amazing!! it seems that this theorem tie moon to the earth...

Answer (score 31):

The claim is true for $\lambda = 0$, when $f(x) = x^n + 1$,
and for $\lambda = 1$, when $f(x) = (x+1)^n$.  We show that this
implies the claim for all intermediate $\lambda$, by proving that
the number of zeros on the unit circle is a non-decreasing
function of $\lambda$.

Let $\lambda = e^t$ with $-\infty < t < 0$, and $x = e^{iu}$ with
$u \in {\bf R} \bmod 2\pi {\bf Z}$.  Then
$$
f(x) = \exp\bigl[t\bigl(\frac{n}2\bigr)^2 + i\bigl(\frac{n}2\bigr)u\bigr]
  \cdot F_t(u),
$$
where
$$
F_t(u) = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}
 \exp\bigl[-t\bigl(k-\frac{n}{2}\bigr)^2 + i\bigl(k-\frac{n}{2}\bigr)u\bigr]
$$
is a real-valued function (the $k$ and $n-k$ terms are complex conjugates,
a symmetry already noted in the comments) and
$F_t(u+2\pi) = (-1)^n F_t(u)$ for all $u,t$.
Now the key observation is that $F$ satisfies the *heat equation*
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} F_t(u) =
  \sum_{k=0}^n -\frac{(2k-n)^2}{4} {n \choose k}
   \exp\bigl[-t\bigl(k-\frac{n}{2}\bigr)^2 + i\bigl(k-\frac{n}{2}\bigr)u\bigr]
= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 \! u} F_t(u).
$$
Thus as $t$ increases the periodic function $F_t(u)$ can lose zeros
(as when two zeros merge and then split into the complex plane)
but never gain them.  Since $F_t$ has $n$ zeros in ${\bf R} / 2\pi {\bf Z}$
for $t<0$ of sufficiently large $|t|$,
while $F_0$ still has an $n$-fold zero at $u = \pi$,
it follows that $F_t$ must still have $n$ zeros for all $t<0$ as well.

*Added later:* Much the same argument proves that for $\lambda>1$
the polynomial has all roots on the negative real axis.  Here we write
$x = e^u$, $\lambda = e^{-t}$, and $f(x) = \exp[-t(n/2)^2+(n/2)u] G_t(u)$,
and again check that $G_t(u)$ satisfies the heat equation because it is
a linear combination of heat-equation solutions
$\exp(tm^2+mu)$ with $m = k-\frac{n}{2}$.
For large $\lambda$ there are $n$ real roots because $f$ changes sign
near the negative root of
$$
{n \choose k-1} \lambda^{(k-1)(n-k+1)} x^{k-1}
+ {n \choose k} \lambda^{k(n-k)} x^k
$$
for each $k=1,\ldots,n$.  For $\lambda = 1$ there is still an $n$-fold root
at $x=-1$, and of course there are no nonnegative roots for any $\lambda$.
Hence $f$ has $n$ negative real roots for all $\lambda > 1$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why $F_t$ can lose zeroes but never gain them ? I am not familiar with the heat equation.

Comment: Good question.  It will be a few days before I can look for a reference
(maybe somebody else here can supply one),
but the intuition is that the heat equation describes the diffusion of heat
as a function of time $t$, from which "no new zeros" follows.  For example,
if a zero appeared in the interior of an interval on which $F$
was positive before, then a local minimum $F(u_0)$ became even smaller
$-$ but the differential equation says its time derivative was
$F''_t(u)$ which is positive near a local minimum, so heat diffusion
would increase $F''_t(u_0)$, not decrease it.

Comment: The non-increase of the number of zeroes seems to be a result of Sturm: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-7643-7359-8_8.pdf

Comment: [correction to my previous comment: heat diffusion would increase $F_t(u_0)$, not $F''_t(u_0)$.]

Answer (score 22):

This follows from Julienne's answer. Fix $\lambda \in (0,1)$ and let
$$ f_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \lambda^{k(n-k)}x
^k. $$
Each $f_n$ satisfies condition (a) for $\mu = 1$. As for (b), we can compute the derivative of $f_n$ to get
$$f_n ' (x) = n \lambda^{n-1} f_{n-1} \left(\frac{x}{\lambda}\right).$$
Now use induction on $n$: for $n=1$ we have $f_1(x) = 1+x$, so $x=-1$ is its only root. If $f_{n-1}$ has all roots on the unit circle, then all roots $x_0$ of $f_n'$ satisfy
$$n\lambda^{n-1}f_{n-1}\left( \frac{x_0}{\lambda}\right)=0$$
and so $x_0=\lambda z_0$ for some $z_0$ on the unit circle, by the induction hypothesis. Hence, as $\lambda \in (0,1)$, $x_0$ lies inside the unit circle. By induction on $n$, (b) holds for all $f_n$ and so the result follows from Cohn.

(Sorry for not leaving this as a comment to Julienne's answer, I do not have enough reputation to comment.)

**Edit:** corrected formula for $f_n'$ thanks to Ian Agol's correction.

Comment: Very nice indeed!

Comment: That is nice. I'll also mention that if you write the polynomial as $f_n(x,\lambda)$ and differentiate with respect to $\lambda$, then there should be some sort of recursion relating $df_n/d\lambda$ to $f_{n-2}$. See my answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296465 for the case that $x=-1$, but the general case should be the same. (But note that $\lambda$ in this problem is $x$ in the other problem!)

Comment: Neat.  The observation relating $f'_n(x)$ to $f_{n-1}(x_0/\lambda)$
should also give an easier route to the result that the roots are
all real for $\lambda>1$.

Comment: There seems to be a typo, I found $f_n'(x)=n\lambda^{n-1}f_{n-1}(x/\lambda)$, which of course doesn't affect the answer.

Comment: For the record: a related paper about  [Grace's theorem](https://www.kth.se/polopoly_fs/1.387444!/Menu/general/column-content/attachment/Grace2.pdf)

Answer (score 19):

In [*Uber die Anzahl der Wurzeln einer algebraischen Gleichung in einem Kreise*, Math. Z., **14**, 1922, 110-148], A. Cohn established the following result:

> Let $p_n(z) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k z^k$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with complex coefficient, then all zeros of $p_n(z)$ lie on the unit circle if and only if $p_n(z)$ satisfies
>
> (a) $a_{n-k} = \mu \bar{a}_k$, $0 \leq k \leq n$, $|\mu| = 1$;
>
> (b) all the zeros of $p'_n(z)$ lie in or on the unit circle.

**Edit** You can find a lot of papers dealing with the same type of problem in the literature and such kind of polynomials are called *self-reciprocal polynomials*.

Comment: Sorry, what does this have to do with the problem?

Comment: I am not sure, but, OP said that he doesn't know how to prove the given problem. So I quoted Cohn's theorem which provides a good idea on how to approach the original problem.

Comment: You were right!

Comment: Very interesting approach, which provides moreover a kind of converse to a special case of the [Gauss-Lucas theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem)!